# How to show hidden UITextFields based on other UITextField input

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have 3 `UITextField`s (location, address, zip). I hide 2 of the fields in `viewDidLoad`.

```
Addres1.hidden = YES;
Zip1.hidden = YES;
```

What I need is when I enter more than 1 number in the Location field, I need to show the address and zip text-fields.
I tried this:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSString *myString=Location.text;
    NSInteger myInt = [myString intValue];

    if (myInt >= 2) {
        Addres1.hidden = NO;
        Zip1.hidden = NO;
    }else{
        Addres1.hidden = YES;
        Zip1.hidden = YES;
    }
  return YES;
 }
```

But it's not working. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong in my code.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSInteger myInt = [myString length];
```

instead of

```
NSInteger myInt = [myString intValue];
```

and write under this method

```
- (void) textFieldDidChange:(UITextField*)textField
```

if you want to compare the number for the input, simply create an array that contains all number you want to compare.

```
NSMutableArray *numberOfArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
  [numberOfArray addObject: i];
}
```

inside this method:
    - (void) textFieldDidChange:(UITextField*)textField

```
if ([numberOfArray containsObject:myInt])
{
  Do whatever you want here !
}
```

Comment: reply instead of Replay

Comment: Then you're still not doing something right. @Bejibun's answer should work perfectly.

Comment: thumbs up for the reputation, if this helps

Comment: @Stonz2 it's tacking only one number like 1 to 9 but i need is more the 1 like 2 to 9 ,10,11..ect also Please give me any idea

Comment: I just added on my answer.

Comment: @Bejibun i check only one number at time please explain why using NSMutableArray

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

}
```

is only called when textfield becomes active so it is only called once so you have to write your logic in

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

}
```

as this delegate is called on every character you enter in textfield

Comment: thanks for reply but it's not for me.it's work when i enter two number like 11,12,22,23,….etc.But it's i need when i enter more then one like 2 to 9 also.